# Как получить название column, который обозначает Id?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Нашел такой вариант:

```
var dtCols = con.GetSchema("IndexColumns", new[] { con.Database, null, table });
```

Нужно найти, название колонки который обозначает Идентификатор (Id) код выше помогает это сделать, но не всегда. А именно index_name - указывает название в виде "PK_{название таблицы}". Но вот у некоторых таблиц имя другое например: PK_HangFire_CounterAggregated.
Где идет совсем другой порядок, где HangFire - это схема, а таблица -AggregatedCounter . Вопрос в том, всегда ли добавляется PK к идентификатору (PRIMARY KEY) или есть ли другой способ найти идентификатор таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть на такой пример [отсюда](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP)

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID,LastName)
);
```

Как видно данный пример нарушает ваши представления о первичном ключе. Имя в принципе можно выбрать самому и колонка вовсе не обязательно быть одной в ключе.

Comment: А может быть в таблице только 2 идентификатора (Many-to-many), Но если рассматривать, именно получение идентификатора. То есть в вашем примере только PK_Person. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Посмотрите на такой пример. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636864/obtaining-a-mysql-tables-primarykey-in-c-sharp-using-odbcconntion-system-data-o

Comment: Спасибо, Этот вариант оказался самым интересным.

'SELECT kcu.column_name
FROM   information_schema.table_constraints tc
INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
ON     tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
AND    tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE  tc.table_schema = '*'             -- only look in the current schema
AND    tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND    tc.table_name = '*'    -- specify your table.'